# Tilt template fragments

Tags: ruby, tilt

Is it possible to render fragments of Tilt templates (i.e., without using a template file on disk)?

Background: I'd like to render inline template strings in a Ruby CGI program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can use any string data:

```
>> require 'haml'
>> template = Tilt::HamlTemplate.new { "%h1= 'Hello Haml!'" }
=> #<Tilt::HamlTemplate @file=nil ...>
>> template.render
=> "<h1>Hello Haml!</h1>"
```

See more examples [in the docs](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/blob/master/docs/TEMPLATES.md)